# Форматируемый вывод значения с плавающей точкой

Tags: форматирование, c++

Нужно вывести на экран значение переменной типа double, при этом нужно чтобы:

- Значение не выводилось в экспоненциальной форме
- А выводилось в простой форме типа `0.ABCABCABC` с точностью, насколько хватит размерности у double.
- Не должно выводиться лишних нулей, т.е., например, при делении 5/2, не должен выводится результат: `2.50000000` и куча ничего не значащих нулей, а должно выводится 2.5.
- При этом double не сразу выводится на экран, а конвертируется в string (а string уже выводится на экран):

-

```
double Res=45;
std::ostringstream ost;
ost<<Res;
std::string buf( ost.str() );
cout<<buf; // вывод на экран
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, а то сколько не экспериментирую с флагами и т.д. , никак не получается удовлетворить трём этим условиям. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: От библиотеки зависит. Чем пользуетесь для IO?

Comment: Да, я совсм забыл уточнить, double не на прямую вывожу в выходной поток, а сначала конвертирую в string:
double Res
std::ostringstream ost;
 ost<<Res;// сдесь пробывал ещё добавлять fixed и setprecision(), 
//но тогда лишнее нули на конце появляются
 std::string buf( ost.str() );
 cout<<buf; // вывод на экран

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    stringstream s;

    s << 5 / 2.;

    string s_out(s.str());
    cout << s_out;

    return 0;
}
```

[Пример](http://ideone.com/BLM7Y) - `C++ (gcc-4.3.4)` -  работает именно так, как Вам нужно.

Так делать не обязательно,

```
std::string buf( ost.str() );
cout<<buf;
```

Потому что `str()` возвращает `string`, по сути Вы выполняете лишнюю операцию копирования.

Comment: Спасибо, но пример из http://ideone.com/BLM7Y, иногда выдаёт результат в экспонинциальной форме.